# Supervise a Python subshell

Tags: python, bash, zsh, subshell

I want to run a Python Interpreter as an inferior process in `bash` or `zsh`. During this time, I would like to send commands to the process and see the output in `STDOUT`. Something like this:

```sh
$ in=/dev/shm/python_test_in
$ out=/dev/shm/python_test_out
$ touch $in $out
$ python < $in > $out
$ echo print(1+1) > $in
$ cat $out
```

Sadly, this does not work. I am running GNU/Linux.

Comment: using `expect` would be the right choice if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a pipe:

```
mkfifo ./in ./out
python < ./in > ./out &
echo "print(1+1)" > ./in
cat ./out
```

However, in this way, the python interpreter will quit immediately after this execution because it read an EOF in the "echo" line. I'm looking for the way to prevent the python interpreter from exiting on EOF.